# Getting value of another input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I've got a little problem on my hands. I am basically trying to get the value of the first input from the second one. The problem? I am using a class as a refference

```
echo "<td>
        <input id='".$row['ID']."' type='text' value='".$row['grade']."' /> /* I want to get the value of THIS input from the input bellow... */
        <input class='grade_change' type='submit' name='".$row['ID']."' value='Change Grade' />
</td>";
```

I basically want to get the value of FIRST input from the second one.

This is my code so far but yeah obviously it will not get the correct input...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".grade_change").click(function() {
        var tmp_id = $(this).attr('name');
        var final = $(this).val(); /* I want to get the value of value='".$row['grade']."' from here */

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

The biggest problem I am facing is quite simnple, I dont know how to select the previous input thats inside the same TD..

Comment: `var final = $('#' + tmp_id).val();`

Comment: Yep yep yep, just realized that one. Thanks mate!

Comment: Optionally just `$(this).prev('input').val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just the ID selector for the `input`:

```
$(".grade_change").click(function() {
    var final = $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).val();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always a guarentee that the other element you want will always immediately preceed the element you are handling the event on you can simply do:

```
$(this).prev('input').val();
```

`prev()` will get the previous sibling of the element, with an optional filter selector.

API Reference http://api.jquery.com/prev/